# NullPointer Exception in LinkedList

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

this is just a silly question,
 why the hell i get exception when deleting an element...
 i just saw this code in my classmate and when i run the code and chooses DELETE i get         NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION

by the way heres the code....(where i get the error)

```
                 if(!(head.data).equals(del)) 
                 {
                     tail=head;   
                     Node temp=head.next;
                     while(temp!=null)
                     {
                         if((temp.data).equals(del))
                         {
                             tail.next=temp.next;
                             size--;
                             break;
                         }
                         tail=temp;
                         temp=temp.next;
                     }
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     head=head.next;
                 }   
                 }
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println("LinkedList is empty"); 
                }
                break;
```

and i'm very glad if someone can help me with this....

full code.
    import java.io.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;

```
public class Main 
{
public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception
{
    BufferedReader x = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
    list.add("Jarn");
    list.add("Zhai");
    System.out.println("List:..");
    //System.out.println();
    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println();

    String ch,in,fi,del;
    boolean kita = false;
    int size=0,data;   
    Node head=null, tail=head; 

    do
    {
        System.out.println("Choose Option.\n1-Insert\n2-Delete\n3-Dispay\n4-Find\n5-Quit");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Choice: ");
        ch=x.readLine();
        System.out.println();
        switch (ch) 
        {
            case "1":
                System.out.println("Enter Name you Want to Insert..");
                in=x.readLine();
                list.addLast(in);
                System.out.println("Name "+in+" was successfully inserted..");
                System.out.println();
                break;
            case "2":
                if(size>=0)
                {  
                 System.out.println("Enter name to del..");  
                 del=x.readLine();

                 if(!(head.data).equals(del)) 
                 {
                     tail=head;   
                     Node temp=head.next;
                     while(temp!=null)
                     {
                         if((temp.data).equals(del))
                         {
                             tail.next=temp.next;
                             size--;
                             break;
                         }
                         tail=temp;
                         temp=temp.next;
                     }
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     head=head.next;
                 }   
                 }
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println("LinkedList is empty"); 
                }
                break;
            case "3":
                System.out.println("List..");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(list);
                break;
            case "4":
                System.out.println("Enter name You Want to Find..");
                fi=x.readLine();
                while(size!=(list.size()))
                {
                    String temp = list.get(size);
                    if(temp.equalsIgnoreCase(fi))
                    {
                        kita=true;
                    }
                    size++;
                }
                if(kita)
                {
                    System.out.println("Name: "+fi+" exists!.");
                    System.out.println();
                }
                else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Name: "+fi+" not found!.");
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                break;
            case "5":
                System.out.println("Thank You..");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("INVALID OPTION..");
                System.out.println();
                break;
        }
    }
    while(!ch.equals("5"));
}
    class Node  
 {  
  String data;   
  Node next;   
  Node(String d)// node class Constructor.   
  {  
        data = d;   
       next= null;   
  }
```

}

}

Comment: Could you post the error [stack trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace)?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Main.main(Main.java:45)
Java Result: 1

Comment: Please edit your question with the full stack trace. Also indicate with line is number `45`.

Comment: if(!(head.data).equals(del)) 
                     {
                         tail=head;   
                         Node temp=head.next;
                         while(temp!=null)
                         {

Comment: The last edit did not improve your post. You removed all the initialisations. I guess the problem is that either `head` or `del` or `head.data` is `null` when you read them. Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: It may be better to post the full method (including header body), so that debugging your code is more straightforward.

Comment: i dunno how to use debbuger..

Comment: @anthraxX:  Now looking at the full code, I'm not convinced it'd compile, let alone be debuggable.  Further to that point, there are some great resources out there that go over how to use a debugger, and I would strongly encourage you to look into them.

Answer (score 2):

It feels like you're trying to hybridize a custom linked list with a `LinkedList` from the Java Collections Framework.   That is likely confusing you.

As it turns out, `List` specifies a [`remove(Object o)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) function that would allow you to remove things **much** more straightforwardly.

That would turn your delete <s>function</s> case statement into:

```
System.out.println("Enter name to del..");  
String del=x.readLine();
boolean removed = list.remove(del);
if(removed) {
    System.out.println(del + " was removed successfully.");
} else {
    System.out.println(del + " isn't in the list!");
}
```

...and from there, you can completely *forget* about the whole custom `Node` business.  It doesn't add anything.

<sup>Take notice:  `del` wasn't defined as a valid variable in your original code, and it's unlikely that you'll ever need it again.  It could be inlined, but I feel this illustrates the syntatic flow better.</sup>

Admittedly, it strongly feels like this is an assignment geared towards having you engineer your *own* linked list construct, but I would triple check the assignment and with your professor/TA on this.

Comment: I was just about to ask him, what is the purpose of using java's LinkedList and creating a self-made remove, I think the question has been answered properly, therefore its a +1 from me.

Answer (score -1):

Before the deletion u need to find the element to be deleted.
Use a while loop.

while(current.data!=n)

```
        {

         prev=current;

         current=current.link;

        }
```

Comment: Maybe if the OP were using their own node structure, and had written a custom linked list implementation, yes.  However, since they're using a plain ol' `LinkedList`, using `remove()` is the appropriate way to do it.